# Am I separating, isolating or modifying the audio or video of a Youtube Video in my Android App?

Tags: youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have a responsive website for kids. Kids can watch selected Youtube Videos in a webbrowser. To make ann Android app, I used an APK creator. This app shows my website in a fullscreen webviewer. I set it up to hide the addressbar, so kids can more safely brows the App (website). On the website are no external links, except the links from the Youtube player. The YouTube video's are loading with a normal Wordpress YouTube plugin. When hitting the YouTube logo or Video URL, the Youtube website wil show.

Now Google Plays said i am violating the rules of the YouTube Api:

"Your API Client will not, and You will not encourage or create functionality for Your users or other third parties to: (8) separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API;"

This I truely not understand. There is no way I want to violate anything. When I appeal for reinstatement the just saying:
"After further review, we are unable to reinstate your application. You can find out more information under Reason for Suspension in the initial removal notification from Google Play."

The initial removal notification said what I wrote above.